# angularjs $window.height is undefined

Tags: angularjs

$window.height is undefined. Where is the problem?

```
FoodSearchControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'filterArgs', function($scope, $http, $window, filterArgs) {
  $scope.popupHeight = $window.height;
  console.log($scope.popupHeight);
}]);
```

Comment: You can use angular.element($window).height()

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`$window`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window) is a wrapper for [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) , and `Window` has no `height` property . You can use `innerHeight` instead, like: `$scope.popupHeight = $window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 8):

You need to include jQuery before angular, it will change the `$window` wrapper to the jQuery `$(window)` object instead of [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `jquery` element by using `var page = angular.element($window);` then get the height `page.height();`

Comment: HI, if you are going to downvote an answer, please leave a comment on why this does not work, because after testing this, it does give the right height, Does it not?

Comment: He doesn't ask about jQuery solutions - it should be pure AngularJS

Comment: @kris_IV to be exact, he asks "why $window.height is undefined", and the answer is that it's a jquery property that is not defined by angularjs. As such, answer mentioning jquery seems to be appropriate and this is, to me, correct answer to question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. Some times window doesnot recognize height.

```
$scope.calculateScreenHeight = function() {
   var height = $window.innerHeight;
   var width = $window.innerWidth;
}
```